# Using custom field as custom post title

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wpalchemy

I've setup a custom post type with a series of custom fields using the WPAlchemy class. I'm trying to take the value of one of the custom fields and use that as the post title. So far, though, I've had no success. I've been browsing around and I've tried the following two different blocks of code:

```
function custom_post_type_title ( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'listing' ) {
        $title = get_post_meta($post_id, 'listing_name', true);
        $where = array( 'ID' => $post_id );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' => $title ), $where );
    }
}

add_action('init', 'listing_save_post');
function listing_save_post( $post_id ) {
        if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && ! DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
        add_action('save_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
        add_action('publish_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
}
```

And.. (temporarily commenting out the nonce fields until I figure out how they work)

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'change_title', 99, 2);
function change_title($data, $postarr)
{    
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    // Verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization because save_post can be triggered at other times
   // if(!isset($_POST['my_nonce_field'])) return;

    // If nonce is set, verify it
   // if(isset($_POST['my_nonce_field']) && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['my_nonce_field'], plugins_url(__FILE__))) return;

       // Combine address with term
    $title = $_POST['listing_name'];
    $data['post_title'] = $title;

    return $data;
}
```

In both cases, the results are the same:

1. On saving the new post, it reloads the page, says it worked, and all of the custom fields are empty. (Without either code set running, the custom post works just fine and the fields are saved).
2. On viewing the custom post type index, the posts aren't there.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I am using a custom post *without* the title support. I am trying to populate the title field nonetheless, though, using the value in the custom field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, every time you save a post, you want to replace the value of a title that just got saved with another value from a custom field...

Seems like you should just put whatever you what the title to be in the actual title field.

BUT I'm assuming this is for presentational purposes: you want that custom post type to display a different title on the front end based on the value of a custom field.  Filters would be an easy way to accomplish this.

`the_title`, the common template tag, is a very thin wrapper around `get_the_title`, which contains a filter called `the_title`. It gets two arguments: the actual title and the post ID.  Hook into that and change the title based on your custom field.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse33385_filter_title', 10, 2 );
function wpse33385_filter_title( $title, $post_id )
{
    if( $new_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_field_name', true ) )
    {
        return $new_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

**A few things about your code to keep in mind:**

Actions don't arbitrarily receive arguments.  Functions hooked into `init` for example, don't get any arguments passed to them.  when `do_action` is called, the first argument is a hook name.  Subsequent arguments are what gets passed to hooked in functions if you desire (specified by the fourth, option arguments of `add_action`).

the `do_action( 'init' );` call is in wp-settings.php.  [Take a look](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/init?version=3.2&file=wp-settings.php), no arguments.

So this:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'listing_save_post');
function listing_save_post( $post_id ) {
        if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && ! DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
        add_action('save_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
        add_action('publish_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
}
```

Is not going to work like you expect.  Moreover, the `add_action` calls inside the function, can just be on their own outside the function...  This works fine:

```
add_action('save_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
function custom_post_type_title( $post_id ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Only need to do stuff on `save_post`, not on that and `publish_post`

I always try to avoid going directly to `$wpdb` if I can, because many times there are more convenient APIs.  What you were trying to do is updated a post.  So use [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).  In your case, that's not a valid option (as the codex states, it can cause an infinite loop).

That was kind of long winded, sorry.  Hopefully it cleared up some things about the WordPress hooks system!

Make these your best friends:

- WP Hooks database: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook
- Wordpress X ref http://xref.yoast.com/

Comment: Christopher, thank you for the detailed thoughts! I'll go through and soak them in more thoroughly. To clarify, though, I am actually trying to pull off a custom post type _without_ using the title field and then have a title show up (made up of a custom field), on the front end, and in the backend (in the list of custom posts). Does that clarify?

Comment: The filter thing I showed you will work for that.  If you want to get rid of the title field entirely, there's an argument in the `$args` array for `register_post_type` called `post_type_supports`, set it like this `'post_type_supports' => array( 'content' )`, no more title on the editing screen.

Comment: That worked! So, I'm using a _filter_, then to pull off the desired effect. If I were to try and retrieve the value, say via WPDB, of the post_title field, I would get the "auto draft" value - correct? The "purist" in me wants to fix that, though I get that the "filter" works. Any thoughts? THANK YOU for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you your filter worked a treat.

FYI

I added a check to see if in Admin to prevent changing the entry-title to my custom "longtitle" (default = menu-item-title) whilst editing a page.

```
function pcdg_filter_title( $title, $post_id )
{
    if(!is_admin())
    {
        if( $new_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'longtitle', true ) )
        {
            return $new_title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title','pcdg_filter_title',10,2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is great, how for example would I add multiple custom fields to this if I wanted it to be for example for a realtor:

location • occupancy • price

as the filtered title instead of just showing one custom field name.

Thanks!