# Copy custom field value to post title

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-field

I used the code found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126764/using-a-custom-field-instead-of-original-title-field-but-only-for-custom-post-ty?rq=1). However, that does not update the title field until you open the post and hit Update button both via the back and front-end. I tried changing "save-post" hook with "edit_post", "publish_artist" and "wp_insert_post_data" but still get the same result. Below is the code I used upon using "wp_insert_post_data" hook.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 2 ); // Grabs the inserted post data so you can modify it.

function modify_post_title( $data )
{
  if($data['post_type'] == 'artist' && isset($_POST['artist_name'])) { // The custom field
    $ArtistName = $_POST['artist_name'];
    $data['post_title'] =  $ArtistName ; //Updates the post title to your new title.
  }
  return $data; // Returns the modified data.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! Finally, I was able to make it work. Below is the complete working code.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 2 ); // Grabs the inserted post data so you can modify it.

function modify_post_title( $data )
{
  if($data['post_type'] == 'artist' && isset($_POST['acf']['field_573676a95d920'])) { // If the actual field name of the rating date is different, you'll have to update this.
    $ArtistName = $_POST['acf']['field_573676a95d920'];
    $data['post_title'] =  $ArtistName ; //Updates the post title to your new title.
  }
  return $data; // Returns the modified data.
}

//Save ACF field as post_title for front-end
add_action('acf/save_post', 'change_artist_title_frontend');

function change_artist_title_frontend($post_id) {
    global $_POST;
    if('artist'== get_post_type())
    {
        $post_custom_title = $_POST['acf']['field_573676a95d920'];
        $my_post = array();
                $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
                $my_post['post_title'] = $post_custom_title;
remove_action('acf/save_post', 'change_artist_title_frontend');
                    wp_update_post( $my_post );
add_action('acf/save_post', 'change_artist_title_frontend');
    } 
}
```