# Using several custom fields as custom post title

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, taxonomy, title

I have stumbled upon a brilliant piece of code that just fits my needs on this thread : [Using custom field as custom post title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33385/using-custom-field-as-custom-post-title) by **@chrisguitarguy** and I was hoping there might be a way to tweak it to use several custom fields' input to populate a CPT's title.

For example, to be sure there will never be any case of twice the same title being generated I would like to use a custom field named `dlc_media_photos_titre` followed by another named `dlc_media_photos_date`, this way I should obtain a title in this format : `Photo gallery name 20210921`.

The date format doesn't really matter, it is just a security to include it in the title.

Thanks in advance (and excuse me if my post is not usual, it is my first one on StackExchange/Overflow).

**edit** Yes I will add the code i am using next time, it's so obvious ! Thanks a lot for your help

**edit 30/06/2022** I have an addition to bring : **@Michelle**'s code works perfectly, but in case you want to combine the value of a Taxonomy with custom fields, this code will work :

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_post_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_post_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    if ( $post_type == 'my-post-type' ) {
        $taxonomy = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'my-taxonomy-name' );
        $taxonomy = $taxonomy[0]->name;
        $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my-custom-field', true );
        $title = $taxonomy . ' - ' . $custom_field;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should include the code you've already tried with your question so we can help with that, just a tip. :) But if you're using the code from that other post as-is, the change would be to this bit:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse33385_filter_title', 10, 2 );
function wpse33385_filter_title( $title, $post_id )
{
    if( $new_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_field_name', true ) )
    {
        return $new_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Where the original only references one custom field, you need to grab two and then use both:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse33385_filter_title', 10, 2 );
function wpse33385_filter_title( $title, $post_id )
{
    $photos_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'dlc_media_photos_titre', true );
    $photos_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'dlc_media_photos_date', true );

    if( $photos_title && $photos_date) {
        $new_title = $photos_title . ' ' . $photos_date;
        return $new_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Note that the line `$new_title = $photos_title . ' ' . $photos_date;` is adding a space between the output of the two fields. If you wanted something else there, a | (pipe symbol) for instance, you could do:

```
$new_title = $photos_title . ' | ' . $photos_date;
```

Comment: I'm now trying to output a new title using a custom field and the post's publish date. I can't get it to work though :

`add_filter( 'the_title', 'dlc_filter_actualites', 10, 2 );
function dlc_filter_actualites( $title, $post_id )
{
    $actualites_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'the_date', true );
    $actualites_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'dlc_actu_titre', true );

    if( $actualites_date && $actualites_title) {
        $new_title = $actualites_date . ' - ' . $actualites_title;
        return $new_title;
    }
    return $title;
}`

(sorry, I don't know how to format)

Comment: @TonioLip To get the published-on date use get_the_date() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/ not get_post_meta. If you are still having trouble after that you should probably open a new question with the code attached :)